# How to convert a partial date for a dataframe in R into a date column?

Tags: r, lubridate

So assuming I have a df like:

```
   <chr>          <chr>            <chr>
  Category        Date             Type
1 x               Jan 2              g
2 x2              Jan 5              a
3 x3              Mar 7              b
4 x4              Apr 9              c 
5 x5              Dec 12             o
```

How would I use the lubridate library to convert my character dates into actual dates?

I've been trying to use lubridate but not sure how to convert the chars into number e.g. Jan into 1, Mar into 3 or directly convert them given that they aren't in the mdy() function scope as they are partial dates.

Comment: A proper date value would also have a year. Do you want to assume all these dates are in the same year?  If so, which year?

Comment: If there is no date, I guess I’d put a placeholder say 2020. How would I do this in R and lubridate? @MrFlick

Answer (score 2):

Just provide a year:

```
x <- c("Jan 2")
as.Date(paste0("2020 ", x), "%Y %b %d")
# "2020-01-02"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
library(lubridate)
mdy(x, truncated = 2)
#[1] "2020-01-02"
```

#### data

```
x <- "Jan 2"
```